# DI of DelegateHandler not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclientfactory

just started working with HttpFactory, and very confused how its DI working, example this line working

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
   .AddHttpMessageHandler(s => new UserAgentDelegatingHandler());
```

this doesn't

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
  .AddHttpMessageHandler<UserAgentDelegatingHandler>();
```

return

> "Message: System.InvalidOperationException : No service for type 'UserAgentDelegatingHandler' has been registered."

Same situation here, following code working fine

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
   .AddHttpMessageHandler(s => new CookieDelegateHandler(s.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()));
```

but this doesn't

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
   .AddHttpMessageHandler<CookieDelegateHandler>();
```

I read a lot of examples of HttpClientFactory usage, my DelegateHandlers from those examples.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? if so can you share ?

Comment: Is it working ?
I tried and it was not working as expected.

Answer (score 9):

> return "Message: System.InvalidOperationException : No service for
> type 'UserAgentDelegatingHandler' has been registered."

As this error indicates, you need to register `UserAgentDelegatingHandler` when you use `.AddHttpMessageHandler<UserAgentDelegatingHandler>()`.

Check [AddHttpMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.addhttpmessagehandler#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-httpclientbuilderextensions-addhttpmessagehandler-1(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-ihttpclientbuilder)), and you will find

> The type of the DelegatingHandler. The handler type must be registered
> as a transient service.

Try to change your code like

```
services.AddTransient<UserAgentDelegatingHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<UserAgentDelegatingHandler>();
```

Comment: If I do it like that, I got `Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler' while attempting to activate 'MyDelegatingHandler`

Comment: @procma that happens if you use the constructor with `HttpMessageHandler` parameter when inheriting `DelegatingHandler`. Try to use the constructor with no parameters